# Find the joint density function $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ of the random vector $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$.

Tags: probability

Choose a point randomly on the interval $[0, 1]$ and label it $X_1$.

Then
choose a point randomly on the interval $[0, X_1]$ and label it $X_2$.

Finally,
choose a point randomly on the interval $[0, X_2]$ and label it $X_3$.

Find the
joint density function $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ of the random vector $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$.

I know $f_{X_1}=1, f_{X_2}=\frac{1}{x_1}, f_{X_3}=\frac{1}{x_2}$

I am not sure how to find $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, i tried to find it :

$f(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x_{1}}\int_{0}^{x_{2}}1\cdot\frac{1}{x_{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{x_{3}}dx_{3}dx_{2}dx_{1}=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x_{1}}ln(x_{2})dx_{2}dx_{1}=\int_{0}^{x}x_{1}ln(x_{1})-x_{1}=(\frac{1}{2}x_{1}^{2}\ln\left(x_{1}\right)-\frac{x_{1}^{2}}{4}-\frac{x_{1}^{2}}{2})|_{0}^{x}=(\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\ln\left(x\right)-\frac{3x^{2}}{4})$

Is my solution correct ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your notation. Also, you're asked to compute a *joint density*, not a *cumulative distribution function*.

You're given that $$X_3|X_1,X_2\sim\mathcal{U}[0,X_2]$$ $$X_2|X_1\sim\mathcal{U}[0,X_1]$$ $$X_1\sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$$ So, $$\begin{eqnarray*}f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3) &=& f_{X_3|X_1,X_2}(x_3|x_1,x_2)f_{X_2|X_1}(x_2|x_1)f_{X_1}(x_1) \\ &=& \frac{1}{x_2} \cdot \frac{1}{x_1} \cdot 1 \cdot 1_{\{0\leq x_3 \leq x_2 \leq x_1\leq 1\}}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thanks , why there is multiply by 1 twice ? $f_{X_3|X_1,X_2}(x_3|x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{x_2}, f_{X_2|X_1}(x_2|x_1)= \frac {1}{x_1} , f_{X_1}(x_1)=1$, am i wrong ?

Comment: I'm emphasizing the formula for each component of my expression. The joint density of the random vector $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ simplifies to $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\frac{1_{\{0\leq x_3 \leq x_2 \leq x_1 \leq 1\}}}{x_1 x_2}$$ I would also write $f_{X_3|X_1,X_2}(x_3|x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{x_2} \cdot 1_{\{0 \leq x_3 \leq x_2 \leq x_1 \leq 1\}}$ to communicate to the reader that $f_{X_3|X_1,X_2}(x_3|x_1,x_2)$ vanishes outside of the interval $[0,x_2]$

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer was to different problem.
For this problem $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\frac{1}{x_1x_2}$ for $0\le x_3\le x_3\le x_1\le 1$  and $=0$ otherwise.  To get marginal distribution for any  variable, need to integrate other two.
$f_{X_1}(x_1)=\frac{1}{x_1}\int_0^{x_1}\frac{dx_2}{x_2}\int_0^{x_2}dx_3=1$
$f_{X_2}(x_2)=\frac{1}{x_2}\int_{x_2}^1\frac{dx_1}{x_1}\int_0^{x_2}dx_3=-ln(x_2)$
$f_{X_3}(x_3)=\int_{x_3}^1\frac{dx_2}{x_2}\int_{x_2}^1\frac{dx_1}{x_1}=\frac{ln^2(x_3)}{2}$

Comment: $\int_{0}^{x_{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x_{1}}\frac{1}{x_{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{x_{1}}dx_{2}dx_{1}dx_{3}$ this is how i supposed to get $f_{X_3}(x_3)$ ?

Comment: @erez Stated marginal distributions are incorrect.   I gave correct values.

Comment: Could you write me please how you get $f_{X_3}(x_3)=\frac{3}{2}(1-x_3^2)$ ?

Comment: @erez To clarify:  $f_{X_2}(x_2|x_1)=\frac{1}{x_1}$ and $f_{X_3}(x_3|x_2)=\frac{1}{x_2}$  Conditional densities, not marginal.  For you question, change order of integration  $f_{X_3}(x_3)=3\int_{x_3}^1 dx_2 \int_{x_2}^1 dx_1$

Comment: Why multiplication by 3 ?

Comment: @erez  I rewrote my answer (corrected).    This should clarify,

Comment: Note recent overhaul of answer.  I had completely misinterpreted your question.